# Matching / Scoring in an Experiment, using instrumental variable (IV) regression for LATEs

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, matching, random-allocation

Maybe this is better suited here, than in economics. I don't know and please excuse the Econ language, I cannot do any better.

I did an experiment with random assignment to two treatment groups and one control group.

I had problems to encourage participation in one treatment (treatment 1), so at the end, I had to randomly assign a lot of people into treatment 2 and control group.

I used the initial treatment assignment as an instrument for actual treatment assignment to have "LATE"s (local average treatment effects).

However, I do not find any statistically significant effects from treatment 1 (maybe due to smaller sample size, as some effects are truly economically meaningful but Standard errors SE are huge).

At a virtual conference, people encouraged me to use either entropy balancing or propensity score matching. However, I have not been able to find any examples where people use this with experiments or with instruments.

It seems to me as people use matching/balancing methods when they have no control group/ no experiment/ no instrument.

Can any of you help and provide hints, how (if) to use balancing or matching with instrumental variables/experiments.

Kindly thank you in advance!

(This is a crosspost from Economics StackExchange)